# Is there any built-in Function in SQL to ignore white space when comparing strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I'm trying to fetch records in SQL server with a query like below.

```
SELECT      TDC_ROW_NUMBER
,           TDC_TD_PARTCODE
            FROM   TD_DATA_PACK_CONTENTS
            WHERE  TDC_IDP_ID = 841
            AND    TDC_TREE_FAMILY_CLASSIFICATION + ', ' + TDC_TREE_CLASSIFICATION + ', ' + TDC_TREE_SUB_CLASSIFICATION + ' , ' + 'A' IN
                   ( SELECT DISTINCT DPC_Level1 + ', ' + DPC_Level2 + ', ' + DPC_Level3 + ', ' + DPC_Status
                     FROM   DATA_PACK_CATEGORIES )
            AND    TDC_TRADE_PRICE > 0.99
            AND    TDC_STATUS = 'RDY'
```

Now the problem i have is the inner query has some records where there are leading or trailing whitespace characters.

So a record looks `'Peripherals, Monitors, Monitors - Medical , A'` and the other string looks like `'Peripherals, Monitors, Monitors - Medical, A'`.

Obviously, this fails when comparing. So is there any function wherein I can trim all the whitespace characters in the entire string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `REPLACE()`:

```
REPLACE(TDC_TREE_FAMILY_CLASSIFICATION + ', ' + TDC_TREE_CLASSIFICATION + ', ' + TDC_TREE_SUB_CLASSIFICATION + ' , ' + 'A', ' ', '') IN
               (SELECT REPLACE(DPC_Level1 + ', ' + DPC_Level2 + ', ' + DPC_Level3 + ', ' + DPC_Status, ' ', '')
                 FROM DATA_PACK_CATEGORIES )
```

You can use the trim functions if you only care about spaces at the beginning/end of a string (actually, spaces at the end are usually ignored ignored anyway).

You can extend the above for additional characters by nesting `REPLACE()` calls.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(text, ' ', ''),',',', ');
```

Inner replace get rid of all whitespaces, when outer adds just single whitespace after each comma.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with regular expressions and are using Oracle (since about Oracle 10.x anyway), there is regular expression support. Some combination of REGEXP_LIKE and REGEXP_REPLACE would do the trick. As an example:

```
declare
  first_string varchar2(1000);
  second_string varchar2(1000);
begin
  select 'Peripherals, Monitors, Monitors - Medical , A' into first_string from dual;
  select 'Peripherals, Monitors, Monitors - Medical, A' into second_string from dual;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Whitespace replacement on first_string yields: ' || 
    REGEXP_REPLACE(first_string,'\s'));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Whitespace replacement on second_string yields: ' || 
    REGEXP_REPLACE(second_string,'\s'));
  if REGEXP_REPLACE(first_string,'\s') = REGEXP_REPLACE(second_string,'\s') then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Yes, they are the same, more or less');
  else
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('My answer is, ''No''');
  end if;
end;
```

When I run that, the DBMS_OUTPUT is:

```
Whitespace replacement on first_string yields: Peripherals,Monitors,Monitors-Medical,A
Whitespace replacement on second_string yields: Peripherals,Monitors,Monitors-Medical,A
Yes, they are the same, more or less
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your SQL, you can just use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DPC_Level1 + ', ' + DPC_Level2 + ', ' + rtrim(DPC_Level3) + ', ' + DPC_Status FROM   DATA_PACK_CATEGORIES
```

Rather than the brute force replace() on the whole string.  This assumes that the trailing space is only ever present on DPC_Level3 - you may want to add it to all elements.