# How do I resolve a SQL-Server query not Recognising whitespace characters?

Tags: sql-server

**Context:** I am using SSMS 2019 to make an email extract from the Hillary Clinton email dataset for a machine learning mail analysis demo. The files have been scraped from WikiLeaks, OCR'd and mostly extracted with some success, I was busy 'sanitizing' the data when I encountered the following problem. There are some related questions such as the following: [Is there any built-in Function in SQL to ignore white space when comparing strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742678/is-there-any-built-in-function-in-sql-to-ignore-white-space-when-comparing-strin) , but these do not exactly answer my question

**Problem:** I have been trying to join two tables on the extracted column [From] and the mapping table column [Original Text], but despite the fact that they should be the same, the extracted [From] has whitespace characters which I cannot clean and thus I cannot match the columns. (The Mapping table [Original Text] column was a copy of the [From] column and uploaded from excel, it seems not have the same whitespace issues)

**What I've tried:** I have used the `RTRIM([From])` and `LTRIM([From])` functions as well as the `REPLACE([From],' ','')`. This last statement I have tried by going through each whitespace char from this site: https://qwerty.dev/whitespace/#beautiful-dingbats as well as trying `CHAR(9)`,`CHAR(13)` and all the whitespace codes in between. I have also copied the whitespaces from the resulting query itself. I tried a few shotgun approaches such as this:
 `LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE([From],'CHAR(9)',''),'CHAR(11)',''),'CHAR(13)','')))`. 
After executing the query, if I copy and paste one of the [From] values, I still end up with seemingly normal whitespace characters in my results. Example: `H<hrod17@clintonemail.com>`.
I try to avoid joining on `[From] LIKE [Original Text]+'%'` becuase the whitespaces aren't necessarily at the end or beginning of the line.

**My Question:** Is there another way of removing the whitespaces from this column? Is this problem from the SQL query itself or might it be some other cuase? A spook whitespace character from another encoding or some settings which I missed possibly?

Here is what my query looks like, I left out everything which is not relevant but I will explain everything should you need more info. Thanks in advance.

```
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

DROP TABLE Temp_CEM
GO
--______________________Table which gets OCRd doc and uses RegEx to extract_______________________
WITH CEM AS
(
SELECT   d.id,
        CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX('|',LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(dbo.fn_RegExMatch([TheText],'(?<=From:).*\s*(Sent:)'),'From:',''),'Sent:',''),' ',''),' ',''))) > 1 
                THEN SUBSTRING(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(dbo.fn_RegExMatch([TheText],'(?<=From:).*\s*(Sent:)'),'From:',''),'Sent:',''),' ',''),' ','')),0,CHARINDEX('|',LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(dbo.fn_RegExMatch([TheText],'(?<=From:).*\s*(Sent:)'),'From:',''),'Sent:',''),' ',''),' ',''))))
            ELSE LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(dbo.fn_RegExMatch([TheText],'(?<=From:).*\s*(Sent:)'),'From:',''),'Sent:',''),' ',''),' ',''))
        END AS [From]
FROM documents d
INNER JOIN Documents_Text t on d.ID = t.Doc_id
INNER JOIN Documents_Folders f on f.ID = d.id 
WHERE f.Folders like '%Clint%'
)
--_______________________Temp table used to speed up Execution time________________________

SELECT * INTO Temp_CEM FROM CEM
GO

--______________________Mapped Person joining to Temp table_________________________________
SELECT top 10
    C.ID
    ,P.[Person]
    ,C.[From]
 FROM Temp_CEM C  left JOIN [DWCONSTRUCTION].[dbo].[Clinton_Person_Mapping_Sheet2] P ON P.[Original Text] = C.[From]
```

The results of this query look like this:

```
ID     Person     From
===========================================
22540  NULL      H<hrod17@clintonemail.com>  
22541  NULL      H<hrod17@clintonemail.com>  
22542  NULL      H<hrod17@clintonemail.com>  
22543  NULL      H<hrod17@clintonemail.com>
```

But it should look like this:

```
ID     Person     From
===========================================
22540  Hillary   H<hrod17@clintonemail.com>
22541  Hillary   H<hrod17@clintonemail.com>
22542  Hillary   H<hrod17@clintonemail.com>
22543  Hillary   H<hrod17@clintonemail.com>
```

Any alternative suggestions would also be greatly appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: I see my example shows leadin and trailing whitespaces in the edit, but not in the post itself. Might be a clue, my question still stands

Comment: What version of sql server

Comment: My guess is that "Mapping table [Original Text] column was a copy of the [From] column and uploaded from excel, it seems not have the same whitespace issues)" is not, actually true. Unless the same whitespace trimming has happened exactly the same on both columns, your join will fail.

Comment: @CaiusJard SQL Server Management Studio 15.0.18206.0 (in Help -> About..), and on the splash screen it shows v18.4. I don't know which reference is the more useful one

Comment: Neither, `select @@version` (SSMS is just a client tool).

Comment: That's not the version of the sql server database, it's the version of management studio, a query tool that can use multiple different SQLS versions. Run `SELECT @@version`

Comment: @DaleK Never knew about that statement, this is the result Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-GDR) (KB4532095) - 12.0.6118.4 (X64)

Comment: Find one of your problem values and `cast(... as varbinary)` to see the bytes composing the string. There's almost certainly something in there that's not a space character since `ltrim()` and `rtrim()` only operate on space characters (ASCII 32 / hex 20). I'd be suspecting errant tabs (ASCII 9 / hex 09), newlines (ASCII 10 / hex 0a) or carriage returns (ASCII 13 / hex 0d).

Answer (score 0):

I know this would be a late answer but just incase any body faces the same problem , I was dealing with that problem for 5 days until I found AlwaysLearning comment(all thanks to him) ... I converted the duplicate values into binary using the
[cast(column_name as varbinary) ]  and I found that the last digit in one of the values was (09) and that refers to [TAB] key  and to replace it you write REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,'press tab here','') and another value was having (0D)
which refers to [Carriage Return] and to replace it you write REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME,CHAR(13),'')....note that none of them are space but it seems like it